# Can body purist have pain-stopper without negative debuff?

Tags: rimworld

Can a colonist with the Body Purist trait have a Painstopper without the negative debuff?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Colonist with the Body Purist trait can have a Painstopper installed **without any negative debuf**.

[image]

*Tested with version 1.0.2282*